# How do we divide $P(x)$ with $ax+b$?

Tags: polynomials

How do we divide $P(x)$ with $ax+b$?
I've tried this:

- $x=-\frac ba$
- $p(x)=(x+\frac ba)Q(x)+v=a(x+\frac ba)\cdot \frac 1a \cdot Q(x)+v$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you divide any polynomial $P(x)$ by $Q(x)$ where $deg(P)\geq deg(Q)$ then the remainder is a polynomial $R(x)$ with $deg(R)<deg(Q)$.

So here you have $Q(x)=ax+b$ so $R(x)=c$, i.e. a constant. By Division Theorem, you can write

$P(x)=(ax+b)D(x)+c$ where $D(x)$ is your quotient.

Put $x=\dfrac{-b}{a}$ assuming $a\neq0$ which gives $c=P(\dfrac{-b}{a})$.

Hence $D(x)=\dfrac{P(x)-P(\dfrac{-b}{a})}{ax+b}$.